# How to bind multiple AuthenticationManager on path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

How can I tell spring to bind bind a `AuthenticationManager` to certain paths?

The following should match a basic authentication manager to all `/rest/**` paths, and ldap authentication to all other paths.

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                @Qualifier("basicAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager basicAuthenticationManager,
                                                @Qualifier("ldapAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager ldapAuthenticationManager) {
                                         
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.mvcMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated())
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .authenticationManager(basicAuthenticationManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .authenticationManager(ldapAuthenticationManager)
            .build();
}
```

Result: when I'm accessing `localhost:8080/rest/test` with `basic authentication`, I'm getting a `401`. Thus I assume the configuration is somehow wrong.

Because when I configure the application with only one `AuthenticationManager`, everything works as expected:

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                @Qualifier("basicAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager basicAuthenticationManager,
                                                @Qualifier("ldapAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager ldapAuthenticationManager) {
                                         
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.mvcMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated())
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .authenticationManager(basicAuthenticationManager)
            .build();
}
```

What might be wrong here? Is it the order in the chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create multiple SecurityFilterChain beans, one bean can only have 1 authentication manager. In your case the cleanest solution in my opinion would be this.

```java
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                @Qualifier("basicAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager basicAuthenticationManager) {
                                         
    return http.antMatcher("/rest/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())  
            .authenticationManager(basicAuthenticationManager)
            .build();
}

public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                @Qualifier("ldapAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager ldapAuthenticationManager) {
                                         
    return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(withDefaults())          
            .authenticationManager(ldapAuthenticationManager)
            .build();
}
```

Alternativly you can use AuthenticationProvider instead of AuthenticationManager you can register more than one of those for each SecurityFilterChain. you would do that something like this (mock code)

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, LdapAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator) throws Exception
{
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasRole("SERVICE") //Something to identify user as another sytem calling your API
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())            
            .authenticationManager(ldapAuthenticationManager);

    LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator = new UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(userDetails);

    http.authenticationProvider(new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticator, ldapAuthoritiesPopulator));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
BindAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator(BaseLdapPathContextSource ldapContextSource)
{
    BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(ldapContextSource);
    authenticator.setUserSearch(new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("ou=people", "(uid={0})", ldapContextSource));
        
    return authenticator;
}
```

Comment: Your first approach looks promising. Though when I add both beans, I'm not getting *any* login form. When I only active the ldap bean, the login form is shown properly. Any guess why?

Comment: the `.httpBasic(withDefaults()) ` was in the incorrect bean, i moved it in the answer. I did the assumption that all `/rest/**` request would be authenticated using an Authorization header with username/password for the rest request and the formlogin with ldap is for the rest of the application. if a form login is required for the rest endpoint for some reason you could add `.formLogin(withDefaults())` to that bean.

Comment: No no, I don't need form login for the `/rest/` endpoint, only for the remaining application. Anyways, the login form is missing for the remaining application as soon as I activate both beans.

Comment: Could you confirm which SecurityFilterChain the other endpoints are using and see if rest calls stil work with both beans active? Only difference in the given example with some of my personal code is that it used AuthenticationManager beans instead of AuthenticationProvider but i don't believe that should matter in this setup

Comment: I discovered that if I move the `.antMatcher("/rest/**")` inside the chain with `.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.mvcMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated())`, then the ldap login form is never shown. If I use your example as is with `http.antMatcher("/rest/**")`, it works. This seems very strange and unpredictable, anyways your code works!

Comment: This is because the outer `http.antMatcher` is there to tell Spring to only use this SecurityFilterChain for objects that match said pattern, the inner matchers in authorizeHttpRequests are only for specifying what authentication is needed for the urls that match. What ends up happening is that spring checks for the the first SecurityFilterChain that matches a given request (using order) and will use that SecurityFilterChain and no other, so higher ordered chains are ignored if a match is found